Can I search for vaccines with openFDA?
I'm trying to get labels for vaccines using OpenFDA. When I search for comirnaty using the NDC endpoint I can see the record:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:0069-2377
When I search for comirnaty under the labels end point there are no records (perhaps because vaccines aren't "drugs"?):
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_ndc.exact:0069-2377
I can see that there is an SPL for comirnaty here:
https://nctr-crs.fda.gov/fdalabel/services/spl/set-ids/48c86164-de07-4041-b9dc-f2b5744714e5/spl-doc?hl=covid-19%20vaccine
Are vaccines searchable on any of the endpoints? Is there an api that allows me to search for biologics/purple book labels?
Thank you! I'm new to this and doing my best to navigate all the terminology.

Thank you for reaching out. No, as a part of openFDA team, I can confirm that we don't have an endpoint for purple book or biologics on openFDA.
Note: I'm a member of openFDA team.
